# How to instantiate base class object using interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I want to instantiate new object of type Dog. Dog class implements interface IAnimal. Animal can make baby animal and that baby animal can grow to be big animal of type dog.

```
public interface IAnimal
{ 
BabyAnimal baby();
int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }

}

public class Dog:IAnimal
{
    public Dog() 
{

}

    public int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }

    public BabyAnimal baby()
    {
    }

}

public class BabyAnimal
{
    public IAnimal WillGrowToBe(BabyAnimal baby)
    {
        //here I want to instantiate new Dog object
    }

}
```

Comment: You can´t create an unspecific instance, meaning just a part of the instance and afterwards completely instantiate it. You either create a dog - I can´t imagine how a baby-dog should grow up to a cat - or create some conversion between different animals - which seems quite odd to me anyway. Having said this I can´t imagine how a `Dog` would get a `BabyAnimal` which grows to a `Cat`.

Comment: A baby Caterpillar grows up to be a Butterfly?

Comment: Drop the BabyAnimal class entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You can model this more strongly, if you introduce the concept of baby and grown animals, in a generic fashion:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    int NumberOfLegs { get;}
}

public interface IBabyAnimal<TGrownAnimal>
    : IAnimal
    where TGrownAnimal : IGrownAnimal
{
    TGrownAnimal WillGrowToBe();
}

public interface IGrownAnimal : IAnimal
{

}

public class Catepillar : IBabyAnimal<Butterfly>
{
    public int NumberOfLegs { get;} = 100;
    public Butterfly WillGrowToBe() => new Butterfly();
}

public class Butterfly : IGrownAnimal
{
    public int NumberOfLegs { get; } = 0;
}
```

You can interact with every one of the animals as a simple `IAnimal` for things like leg count, and nicely, you can write something like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TGrown GrowUp<TGrown>(this IBabyAnimal<TGrown> baby)
        where TGrown : IGrownAnimal
    => baby.WillGrowToBe();
}
```

Which you can then use against *any* baby animal to get the grown form.

Comment: You forgot the `Baby`-method which create a new `IBabyAnimal<T>`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere indeed I did, but we're not here to write code for people, we're here to answer questions and show them ways of doing things; if OP is suitably motivated, they can apply this approach the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *distinguish* baby animal (e.g. `Pup`) and adult one (`Dog`) you can implement `3` interfaces:

```
// Animal in the most general: all we can do is to count its legs
public interface IAnimal { 
    // get: I doubt if we should maim animals; let number of legs be immutable
    int NumberOfLegs { get; } 
}

// Baby animal is animal and it can grow into adult one
public interface IBabyAnimal : IAnimal { 
    IAdultAnimal WillGrowToBe()
}

// Adult animal can give birth baby animal
public interface IAdultAnimal : IAnimal { 
    IBabyAnimal Baby();
}

// Dog is adult animal, it can birth pups
public class Dog : IAdultAnimal {
    public Dog() 

    public int NumberOfLegs { get; } => 4;

    public Baby() => new Pup();
}

// Pup is baby animal which will be dog when grow up
public class Pup : IBabyAnimal {
    public Pup() 

    public int NumberOfLegs { get; } => 4;

    public WillGrowToBe() => new Dog();
}
```